# The importance of three spatial dimensions and QFT cross-sections at low energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, spacetime-dimensions, scattering-cross-section

I'm trying to refresh my memory and gain some more intuition for cross-sections. For simplicity I have in mind only self-interacting scalar fields of mass $m>0$ interacting according to a polynomial potential $g \phi^n$. I want to know whether cross-sections vanish or diverge as the velocity of the particles tends to zero and how this depends on the spatial dimension $d_s$.

Up to factors of $2$ from indistinguishability, I believe (please correct me if I'm wrong!) that the differential total cross-section for two $\phi$ particles to scatter into two $\phi$ particles in terms of the Mandelstam variable $t$ is

$$\frac{d\sigma}{dt} = \frac{(\frac{1}{4}(s-4m^2))^{(d_s-5)/2}}{4 (2\pi)^{d_s -1} s } |A|^2 $$

where $A$ is the scattering amplitude. Here the dimensional dependence of $d_s$ in the exponents of $(s-4m^2)$ is coming from powers of $|\vec{k}'|$ in the center of mass frame; that is, it comes from factors of $|\vec{k}'|^{d_s -1}$ from phase space factors of $d^{d_s} \vec{k}'$ describing the ways the scattered particles can move after being scattered. Note that $s$ is the center-of-mass energy squared $(2 E)^2 = 4(\vec{k}^2 +m^2) \geq 4m^2$.

Thus, we have

$$\sigma = \frac{(\frac{1}{4}(s-4m^2))^{(d_s-5)/2}}{4 (2\pi)^{d_s -1} s } \int_{-(s-4m^2)}^{0} |A|^2 dt$$

The result's dependence on $d_s$ on the outside of the integral seems reasonable. Loop corrections of the amplitude will probably enter in powers of $g s^{\frac{1}{4}( (n-2)d_s -(n+2))}$ by dimensional analysis up to logarithmic corrections, so, assuming one only has renormalizable interactions, the lowest nontrivial level of scattering will largely determine the $s$ dependence of the cross-section.

Consider the limit as $s-4m^2 << 1$, then, assuming $|A|^2$ is finite at $s=4m^2$, one has

$$\sigma \sim \frac{(\frac{1}{4}(s-4m^2))^{(d_s-3)/2}}{4 (2\pi)^{d_s -1} 4m^2 } |A(s=4m^2)|^2 \propto (s-4m^2)^{(d_s-3)/2}$$

It appears that having three spatial dimensions is privileged. For $d_s <3$, the cross-section diverges at low energy, for $d_s > 3$ the cross-section vanishes at low energy, while for $d_s=3$ the cross-section can be a finite number.

---

This result is surprising to me. I know that one answer to the question of "Why three spatial dimensions?" shows that solutions of Poisson's equation lead to potentials yielding stable orbits in three spatial dimensions alone. However, the low-energy limit of the theory should correspond to long-distance physics where the mass of the particle should introduce an exponential decay of interaction, so I wouldn't have expected such dependence on dimension for the low-energy behavior of the theory.

---

First, is my analysis of the asymptotics at low energy correct? If it is, is there an intuitive reason why particles in $1$ and $2$ spatial dimensions scatter much more strongly at low energy, and $4$ and higher spatial dimensions scatter very weakly at low energy, despite the length scale provided by $m$?